# How to work with an Excel Sheet values to change them as variables in my release definition

Tags: excel, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Am working on VSTS DevOps where only on release definition. Actually, our client need not to do us Build Definition, they need only deployment for them and they are providing drop folder for that. But, here what my requirement is” We need to change the variables with the base of an Excel Sheet values”. Because our client values are providing us in an Excel Sheet format. Can anyone suggest me to “how to work with an Excel Sheet values to change them as variables in my release definition”

Answer (score 0):

There is no such settings to get the variables and their values from excel for VSTS release definition.

The workaround is **add the variables and their values in VSTS release definition by program**. The main aspects for the program should achieve as below:

1. Get variables and their values from excel

   Assume the variables’ name located in column A and their values located in column B, you can loop to get the variables and values.
2. Update VSTS release definition (add variables) by REST API

   Detail format for update a release definition, you can refer [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions#update-a-release-definition).

   And if you want to execute the REST API by PowerShell, you can refer [aseemb’s blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2017/04/06/vs402903-the-specified-value-is-not-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-make-sure-it-is-convertible-to-type-releasedefinition-and-try-again/).